# simple responsive design \ best practice

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, polymer

Consider two `inline-block` divs. Now, I want when the user decrease the browser size, that only one `<div>` will stay visible (and not one `<div>` to go to the next line...).

How can I implement that?

```
<style>
    div {
        display:inline-block;
    }
</style>
<div id="first">this should dissapear on narrowing browser</div>
<div id="second">only this should be visible</div>
```

I use Polymer, so if there is some syntax sugar here would be nice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this! http://jsbin.com/bibuzu/1/edit

There's a breakpoint at 480px so any widths before then the first div is set to display none and the second div takes up the rest of the space.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  div.first {
    display: none;
  }

  div.second {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [media queries](https://www.google.com/search?q=css%20media%20queries&oq=css%20media%20queries). Two possible approaches to this problem:

- Set `display:none` on the div to hide it at a certain screen resolution
- Wrap the two divs in another one with `overflow:hidden` on the wrapper

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a media query, e.g.:

### [**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wNFEF/)

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) { /* <--e.g. hide at 640px.. */
     div:first-child{ /* <--selector to identify the div you want to hide */
         display:none;    
    }
}
```

Comment: tried that and it is working :) however - seems like when I narrow it slowly there is some point it lies one beneath the other only when narrowing more it disappears..how can I have only 2 states?